# I can't access a public variable within a sub class in main?

Tags: c#, variables, xna, subclass, base-class

Can anyone assist me?

I'm making a game on XNA.

I have a GameObject class that acts as a base class for `Character.class` or `Object.class`

There's also `Game.class`

I just wanted to ask, I have a subclass of `GameObject` which has a public variable called `canJump`.

For some reason I can't even access the variable.

I have `GameObject character = new Character();`

This object can easily access all the overridden functions of the base class but it won't allow me to use public variables.

Comment: think an example: (Human extends Animal) All Humans are Animal, but not all animals are human

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, the compiler doesn't know that the `GameObject` is actually a `Character`. Unless you have a good reason not to, just use `Character`:

```
Character character = new Character();
```

Comment: Hmmm the compiler doesn't know eh?  That's strange... how does it know to use overridden functions?  And private variables within the subclass?

Comment: @user819511: It doesn't. The runtime does. As for the subclass, the compiler does know that the subclass is derived from the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is the keyword here. Minitech is correct, all the compiler knows is its a GameObject, so you only have access to GameObjects interface. You can use the overidden methods because they are also part of the GameObjects interface, tho at run time you will actually get Character's version of that method. In your code you can do things like:

```
if(character is Character) //Character being the subclass
{
    (character as Character).DoSomeCharacterSpecificStuff;
}
```